# How to index when all columns are searchable?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a large table of persons that have info about their appearance and skills like age, eye color, hair style, plays piano, etc

All these fields are searchable so a user can search for someone that plays guitar and have blue eyes.

How to deal with indexes in this particular case? I know that I cant create index for all columns because it will affect the write time. So whats the best approach for this scenario?

Comment: Sample data would help, along with examples of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't index every possible combination optimally. For example, if you want to search for `plays_guitar=true` and `eye_color='blue'` you'd need a compound index on the pair of columns `(plays_guitar, eye_color)`. The order of columns in the index doesn't make much difference if both conditions are equality, but having the compound index does help a lot.

The trouble is, this means you'd need not only an index for every column, you'd need all possible combinations. So 2<sup>*n*</sup> indexes for *n* columns.

But there's also inequality conditions to account for. For example, if you want to search for `plays_guitar=true` and `eye_color <> 'blue'`, the latter condition is an inequality. Then the order of columns in the index *does* matter. You can have multiple columns used for equality conditions, first in the index. Then you can have *one* column used for an inequality condition follow the other columns.

So you don't merely need 2<sup>*n*</sup> indexes, you need indexes for all *permutations* of columns (that is, combinations but with significant ordering), which is on the order of *n*! indexes. Clearly this is not possible given the practical limits of a database.

The only options are to index *some* of the columns that are searchable, and hope that narrows down the search sufficiently. Conditions on additional columns that aren't in the index will be evaluated row by row. This is where you get a high number of "rows examined" in your query execution.

This is not as good as finding the rows solely by index lookups, but maybe not a deal-breaker.

So it's up to you to design a limited set of indexes that are going to be "good enough" to narrow down the most likely searches.

Welcome to being a professional software engineer — you need to use your judgment and experience, and you can't optimize all possible outcomes.

If you are told the searches are totally unpredictable and all possible searches should be treated as equally likely, then that's not a scenario that can be solved, at least not with B-Tree indexes.

Then you can try adapting the data to a fulltext search architecture, where you *can* index the whole dataset and search for values in arbitrary combinations of columns.

Currently the most popular example of such a database is Elasticsearch, which is based on the open-source Apache Lucene search engine.

Apache Solr is another good choice, if you want to stick to open-source offerings (the latest version of Elasticsearch is no longer open-source).

Answer (score 1):

Creating indexes  is always a trade-off. You made a part of that trade-off yourself: you can't create an index for each column, because of the write-speed. How many indexes you can create depends on your trade-off between read-speedup and write-slowdown. That's for you to decide: if you update the table nightly outside office hours and only read during day-time, the trade-off is different that when you continuously update.

If your trade-off says you can create only 2 indexes, you might want to create them where they have the most impact. Which columns are those? We obviously don't know, but you may get some hints:

- do you use views with merges? They could be faster with indexes.
- do you have any statistics on the use? If a column is in 99% of all queries, that column is definitely a candidate for an index.
- do you have a number of fixed queries? You could speed those up with well chosen indexes.
- how many different values are there in a column? For example: has a driver-license is yes/no. An index on those colums is less effective that an index on age (ranging from 0-122 years and 164 days).
- do you have any policies, f.e. using queries on age is discouraged? In that case, you would not put an index on the age.

These are a few points to consider. As your question was quite generic, my answer is necessarily too.